# Possible to modify an enum in a third-party ActiveX control?

Tags: java, com, enums, activex

I am using an ActiveX control from a vendor for a USB device that reads RFID cards.

My application is in java and so I am using EZJCom as a "bridge" - all of the properties and methods of the activeX control are therefore available via java classes.

If I look in windows device manager, the card reader device is on com port `COM8`.

Now, the problem occurs because of this enum, which indicates the COM port the device is running on.

```
typedef enum {
    COM1 = 1,
    COM2 = 2,
    COM3 = 3,
    COM4 = 4
} CommPortConstants;
```

My Java code can do this:

```
cardReader.get_DMF5Ax().setCommPort(CommPortConstants.COM4);  // OK
```

But not this:

```
cardReader.get_DMF5Ax().setCommPort(CommPortConstants.COM8);  // fails!
```

In other words, due to the nature of this enum, I can't look for the device (via java calling the ActiveX control) on `COM8`.

So for my question: is there a way to "edit" an ActiveX control, and add values to the enum?

Or is there a better way (other than EZJCom) to use activeX controls from java.

Note that I don't have the source code to the ActiveX control, and (coming from the java world) neither am I familiar with the development environments for making them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about EZJCom (and very little about Java for), but from the ActiveX/COM I don't think you should have a problem working it around.

COM methods (and specifically, automation methods) do not get Java Enums. They either get LONG in most cases, and in some cases, they would get VARIANT or type I4.

It looks like CommPortConstants are just constants, so this should work for you:

```
cardReader.get_DMF5Ax.setCommPort(8)
```

Comment: Hi Uri, thanks for your answer, however the EZJCom program has made an interface to the activeX control that unfortunately only accepts the enum. I looked for a method accepting `int` but I didn't find one.

Comment: I tried this `cardReader.get_DMF5Ax().JComSetProperty("CommPort", new JComVariant[] {new JComVariant(8)})` but it gives me exception: `ezjcom.JComException: Parameter not optional. (0x8002000f)`... :(

Comment: With no knowledge of EZJCon, I'm going to speculate that if EZJCon exposes IDispatch functionality, maybe you can use the lower level API's: GetIDsOfNames and Invoke?

Comment: Then, on a completely different level, and if you can find an available port in COM1 to COM4, maybe you can map the Win32 name (a.k.a. DosDevices name) 'COM4' to the actual device COM8. Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546502(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I can't see any IDispatch functionality, though I found a generic method `cardReader.JComSetProperty("CommPort", new JComVariant[] {new JComVariant(8)})` which failed with Exception: `ezjcom.JComException: Parameter not optional. (0x8002000f)`

Comment: I did think about trying to re-arrange the ports, I'll read more about it, but ideally I want to deploy this software without having to do windows configuration first.

Comment: Few more thoughts: You need to find out whether com1 to com4 is a vendor limitation or a limitation coming from EZJCom. For that, why don't you implement a short C++ application consuming your vendor ActiveX. Learn what type of parameters are acceptable. If setCommPort accept integers up to 8 or not. If problem is in vendor - there isn't much you can do. If problem is in EZJCon, I would just look for a different, more transparent solution.

Comment: Uri, I found a way to modify the EZJCon java code after it is generated and before the jar is created. But thanks for your tips in any case.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, since you suggested to find a work-around and pointed out that activeX controls use LONG or similar data types.